# IDEA "never accessed" warning on increment operator ++

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings, increment

IDEA shows a warning if a increment **int** with **++** or **+=** operators.
It can only be fixed if I increment in a explicit way **int=int+1**.

[image]

Is it a bug or a feature?

**EDIT:** Ok, it's a feature of IDEA. But it seems to me wrong. We obviously can't increment something without accessing the initial state. Would we have operator overloading we can think of **++** as of a function with argument **i**.

So, the question is: is it possible to change this behavior in IDEA?

Comment: It's a feature of the IDE. Those operations on the variable `cnt` have no bearing on the application execution, except for the time they take.

Comment: I assume it's giving that warning because the value of cnt is "looked up and used" with the ++ or += operators.In the case of "cnt = cnt + 1" it's "looking up the value" and then storing it back into cnt.

Comment: If the IDE was even smarter, it would keep the warning even with `cnt = cnt + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a feature, you can customise which ones show and what level of warning they give in Intellij by going to **Project Settings** - **Insepections**

There is a huge list which you can turn on and off or customise.

This one is due to the variable is never used even though you are incrementing it, it is never explicitly read by another statement.

And if you do `i = i + 1` it still gives that warning just on the new assignment like so (well that's a new warning I see now)

[image]

The warning you are after is in **Declaration redundancy** - **Unused Symbol**

You can configure this for what it checks or to ignore with special annotations but not how it behaves in your instance.

I think that it is still valid for the IDE to give that warning as the operations **++** and **+=** are only accessing it to assign it to itself... what the point if you are then not using it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the warning, as you are not reading the variable out, merely incrementing it.

It's a feature.